# Hibernate and Sql Server best Practicies

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, hibernate

Our application uses Hibernate with Sql Server 2005.

Being a DBA, I am not an expert of Hibernate yet. And our developers do not understand Sql Server very well, so I need a middle ground to make sense out of this.

I am looking for some info on how Hibernate works with Sql Server 2005. Any best practices or any issues with the combination or anything like 'lessons learnt'.

I do not have any particular question as such, but in general if there is anything that I need to know to improve the performance overall.

Please let me know if you have links to any such articles.

thanks,
_UB

Comment: This question is to general, I don't think that you get any answers. With NHibernate, SQL Server is quite common and well supported. So => just read the docs...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've been trying to read as much material as I could get my hands on. But so far I've only been able to get general stuff without any Sql Server related material. 

Any help would be great...

Comment: When reading about NHibernate, the general stuff usually applies to Sql Server. There are not much specific about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some titbits that i learned when i used hibernate :

> 1. Dont hard code queries with params. Use named queries. For more info click
>      [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91885316.html)
> 2. Make sure you dont append params to query strings to avoid sql injections
> 3. You can use stored procedures whenever necessary to update data
>      (AFAIK, Hibernate doesnt support
>      nested transactions)
> 4. Use the container features to Encrypt passwords needed to connect to
>      db.

I ll add as and when i come up with certain best practices.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to Cshah's statement:
Use caching when it is appropriate... if you are inserting a ton of items into a database that you don't plan on caching, set the Cachable attribute to false before you save.